# Creating new Lumen app on nginx throwing 404 when hiting IP Adress through browser

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, lumen

I am trying to create a plain Lumen application on Nginx server on Digital Ocean. Following the [official documentation for Laravel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-lts-vps), I followed everything as it is said until the Laravel Installation bit.

Just instead of this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel /var/www/lumen/ 4.1
```

I used

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen blog` instead.
```

The Lumen document seems on the directory now when I use `ls`.

However when I hit the IP address, or IPAdress/index.php, it shows

> 404 Not Found - nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

---

Also, this is my configuration for Virtual Host file (`nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`)`:

```
server {
        listen   80 default_server;

        root /var/www/laravel/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong or missing?

---

Also, if I try connect to the SSH directory with PhpStorm, I received an error:

```
ssh://root@46.101.172.134:22null /usr/bin/php
env: /var/www/Lumen: Permission denied

Process finished with exit code 126
```

Please also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781054/fetching-laravel-directory-from-ssh-into-phpstorm) for further info on this error..

---

**Edit 2:**

I tried changing my server to..

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    listen 443 ssl;
    
    root /var/www/lumen/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name IPAddress;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;    // I didn't set this
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;  //  and this

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using index.php in the route? do you get a 404 if you hit your ip address in the browser. Also do you have anything being returned in your routes file.

Comment: I have Lumen installed so it should have a route for `ipaddress/`. If I hit the ip address, I receive [the 404 error](https://geekflare.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/nginx-errorpage.png)

Comment: **The answer is updating the SSL certificate details**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04) to create an SSL Certificate on nginx. Then, hitting http://ipaddress gives me the Lumen/Laravel stuff.