# How can I get Lumen 5.4 routes to work on nginx 1.12.1?

Tags: nginx, lumen

The issue is that apart from the '/public' route, no other route works.. e.g routes like '/public/test' throws 404 error. I have googled and tired every suggestion, still no solution. I have also tried the links below, they all didn't work for me. I using Amazon AMI Linux version.

[Creating new Lumen app on nginx throwing 404 when hiting IP Adress through browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779743/creating-new-lumen-app-on-nginx-throwing-404-when-hiting-ip-adress-through-brows)

[Laravel routes not found on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493634/laravel-routes-not-found-on-nginx)

Here is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  18....my_ip;
    #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root /var/www/html/dev;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_par
```

Comment: Post the nginx logs showing error

Comment: your nginx root should point to `/var/www/html/dev/public` directly. Not `/var/www/html/dev`, because it's just the root of your Lumen application. On production enviroment, you should point it to `public` directory of Lumen. Don't forget to restart `nginx` after changing.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra
I have tried using `/var/www/html/dev/public` as the `root`, same issue. Besides, I can access the home page using `http://my_ip_address/public` even when the root is pointed to `/var/www/html/dev` but the issue is other routes like `http://my_ip_address/public/foo` do not work whether or not I attach public to root or use it in the url

Comment: @TarunLalwani I do not see any error when I access `sudo vi /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: I'think the problem is on url rewriting, try change your `try_files` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?$query_string;`. Because rewriting should against the file `index.php` inside `public` directory

Comment: @DharmaSaputra Perfect! it worked! Thanks guys.